# Long table and subfigure in a journal template

Tags: longtable, subfloats

In [this](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/transportation-science-(informs-journal)) latex template on which I'm working, the following snippet is used to embed figures and tables into it:

```
\begin{figure}
\FIGURE
{\includegraphics{figure-filename.pdf}}
{Text of the Figure Caption.\label{fig1}}
{Text of the notes.}
\end{figure}

 and 

\begin{table}
\TABLE
{Text of the Table Caption.\label{tab1}}
{\begin{tabular}{<table format>}
entries
\end{tabular}}
{Text of the notes.}
\end{table}
```

I need to use `longtable` and `subfigure` environments, but when I put them in the template above, it doesn't work. I even tried something different than the quoted format, however the caption's style will not be the same as considered one in the template.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a short but complete and compilable example document that we can use to reproduce your issue. No one of us can guess what your LaTeX template might look like.

Comment: And it would be good you add a link to the template you use to your question!

Comment: You cannot use `longtable` inside a table environment. `longtable` does not float.

Comment: This link contains the template that I mentioned in my question https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/transportation-science-(informs-journal)

Comment: The big question is what `\FIGURE` and `\TABLE` do.  I suppose it is documented somewhere in the link, but I have no desire to search for it.

Comment: I found the solution in another discussion titled : "about figure in minipage". and it perfectly work for images. Now, I just have to find the solution for the longtable.